# Funnel a flat file and database table

Tags: datastage

I'm trying to combine two table one in flat file and other in database using a funnel. On the funnel output columns are displaying different column names even though I have changed the name of flat files columns.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you show some sample records?

Answer (score 0):

A funnel stage requires all input metadata to be identical. Have you taken a look at the [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/c_deeref_Funnel_Stage.html?lang=en) for this stage?